# Using the nupack Package Manager Console to set working folder to solution folder

Tags: powershell, nuget

In Visual Studio, nupack adds a power-shell window called the Package Manager Console. I am thinking that this would be a good place to run source control commands (I'm using Mercurial). However, the default working directory is my users folder, so I need to navigate to my code folder every time I load a new project.

I am wondering if there is a one-line command to set the working directory to the solution folder. e.g. does something like this exist?

```
cd $SolutionFolder
```

From the results of `get-variable` it doens't look like there is anything immediately available, but I've never used powershell before, so maybe there is a way of getting the solution folder?

Comment: Glad to find that "Package Manager Console" is just a Power-Shell window; I didn't know what flavor of syntax it used otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Doug for pointing me in the right direction. I've written up full instructions on my blog here:

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2010/10/change-to-solution-folder-in-package.html

The basic answer is that the following command will do it:

```
Split-Path -parent $dte.Solution.FileName | cd
```

To make it more readily available, you need to create a function in your "user profile" script file, the location of which is found in the `$profile` variable. You will need to create the file if it doesn't exist. Then add a function:

```
Function solutionFolder()
{
    Split-Path -parent $dte.Solution.FileName | cd
}
```

Now, after loading a solution in VS2010, you can simply type:

```
solutionFolder
```

and the working folder will be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$dte.Solution.FileName
```

Comment: thanks, this is moving me in the right direction. I can now do `Split-Path -parent $dte.Solution.FileName` to get the folder. Now I need to work out how to set up the package manager console to have this available in a variable or command without having to type that in every time

Comment: You can find the PowerConsole profile in this variable $PowerConsoleUserProfile. There you can setup functions etc to shortcut what you need to do.

Comment: it seems to be $profile, but thanks I've managed to get it working now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when it changed, but the Package Manager Console automatically shifts the working directory to the current solution folder when you open an application now.